# Determine if azure blob is still uploading

Tags: azure-storage

Scenario:
A big blob is being uploaded to azure storage from a third party vendor.
The vendor sends us the message that the blob is being uploaded through a web service.
The vendor does not know if the whole blob is completely uploaded before they send the message to the service.

Error message:
I am getting the error message "Blob not found" when I try to to download the message using method DownloadToStream.

Question:
Is there any way I can determine if the blob is still uploading or the blob is not complete?

AJ

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to get also the message when the blob upload is done?

Also take a look at [leases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691972.aspx). It might be solution for you.

Comment: Absolutely, to get the message when the blob is uploaded would be the easiest way. But that is out of my control. I have to make a robust solution on my side that can handle this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot easily be determined if you do not have insight into the vendor's uploader application. There are two types of blobs:

1. Block blobs

   - They are not committed until Put Block List is called and the Blob service will keep returning 404 until that time.
   - However, if the uploader does more than one Put Block List calls to the blob (to completely overwrite or modify/append some blocks), the blob can be downloaded right after the first Put Block List call.
2. Page blobs

   - They can be downloaded right after the Put Blob call to create the blob even though they are completely empty at that time.